# Boot Repair help needed

Tags: boot-repair

About 10 days ago, I installed Peppermint 10 to along side my Ubuntu 18.04.3. Several days, I no wanted Peppermint so I deleted its partition or I thought I did. After too much redoing and changing the HDD, I ended up with three partitions, each I think contains Ubuntu 18.04.3. After using Boot Repair that was installed by using sudo apt-get, they suggested I post my Boot Report and I posted it to: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Pkd3yTXktD/

After looking at the report at the above stated URL, I am appealing for help in restoring my original HDD into one partition instead of having three partitions. Thanking you in advance, I remain sincerely appreciated. FWIW, my backup data install on my stick drive failed me completely. That was something I was not expecting at all. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Lilo is a Windows type boot loader. You just need to reinstall grub. Boot-Repair's default suggestion is your install in sda1. But if you want either of your other installs, as default boot, use Boot-Repair's advanced mode and choose that install & sda for grub bootloader. Menus: https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: It is unclear if you want help with boot repair or with edition partitions. It  is also unclear what was the result of boot-repair operation.